Controlling Default User Access When Installing New Modules in Odoo
When installing a new module in Odoo, all users are automatically granted access to it by default. How can I configure Odoo to prevent this automatic access and instead assign access permissions only to specific users afterward?

Search for the groups that are assigning the automatic rights while installing and see in the code regarding the implied_ids for group "group_user." if it is there, then it means that odoo is assigning the rights automatically to internal users, so you have to remove it.
Example:
Odoo default Code:
<record id="group_account_readonly" model="res.groups">
<field name="name">Show Accounting Features - Readonly</field>
<field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_hidden"/>
<field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>

You have to customize as below:
<record id="account.group_account_readonly" model="res.groups">
<field name="name">Show Accounting Features - Readonly</field>
<field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_hidden"/>
<field name="implied_ids" eval="False"/>

